# Python regex to match HTML

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to request a web page via urllib2 using a regex.

Here is my code

```
def Get(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    page = urlOpener.open(request)
    return page.read()

page = Get(myurl)
#page = "<html>.....</html>" #local string for test
pattern = re.compile(r'^\s*(<tr>$\s*<td height="25.*?</tr>)$', re.M | re.I | re.DOTALL)
for task in pattern.findall(taskListPage):
```

If I use a local string (same as `Get(myurl)`' s result) for test, the pattern works, but if i use `Get(myurl)`, the pattern does not work.

I will be grateful if someone can tell me why.

Comment: Please read the top answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: As Jim's comment points out, trying to parse HTML with regex will eventually drive you to the brink of insanity. I suggest using a [more powerful parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) that can handle non-regular languages better and is more resilient to minor page modifications.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556141/regex-to-extract-favicon-url-from-a-webpage/6556360#6556360

Comment: Not worth being questioned: it has been discussed numerous times that regexes are the appropriate choice for parsing HTML. Do your research first.

Comment: @user299654 Please, explain more your problem, I don't understand it as exposed. What do you mean by _"If I use ... , but if I use ..."_ : what action is supposed the verb 'use' to describe ? What is **taskListPage** ? Why obtaining **page** with ``page = Get(myurl)`` if it isn't employed  after this instruction ? By the way , ``r'^\s*(<tr>$\s*<td height="25.*?</tr>)$'`` IS a pattern, and ``re.compile(r'^\s*(<tr>$\s*<td height="25.*?</tr>)$', re.M | re.I | re.DOTALL)`` is a regex (a RegexObject, more exactly).

Answer (score 1):

Valid reservations about using regex on html aside, try this regex instead:

`(<tr>\s*<td height="25.*?</tr>)`

You were finding only matches at end of input `$`, and had problem terms at front of regex.

This match is a brittle - let's hope the web guy doesn't change the `height` of the rows...